# Python and mySQL UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, utf-8, ascii

I really need your help please

I'm exporting data from a mysql DB with a simple python script.
However when i print the results, i get some UTF-8 characters in one of the fields and when i print it using tabulate it gives me the following popular error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte"
The main objective is to print the exact data that are on the DB.

How do you suggest to solve this?

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

The code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="user",
  password="password",
  database="database",
  #charset='ascii' -> if i use this i can print with tabulate but some characters are replaced with ?
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7, column8, column9, column10, colum11 FROM database LIMIT 5")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
    print ('\n')
    print(x)  # Here i can print the results with for example "Situa\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o com impacto em monitoria e despiste"

print(tabulate(myresult, headers=['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6', 'column7', 'column8', 'column9', 'column10', 'colum11'], tablefmt='psql')) 
# And here i get the error "... UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte... "
```

Comment: `"Situa\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o"` is mojibake (`"SituaÃ§Ã£o"`).  It looks  like maybe UTF-8 data has been written to a database that expects latin-1 (this used to be the MySQL default encoding, I don't know if it still is).  `"Situa\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o".encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')` will give you the original characters.

Comment: Thank you. But to do that, i have to do it to all the data i receive from that column.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`